# How to find the number of cells in a table that don't contain an image of a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have a table like:

```
<table>
  ...
  <td class="projectapproval">
    <img src="../../Content/Images/stock_lock.gif" alt="locked" class="lockicon invisibleforprint" />
  </td>
  <td class="projectapproval">
  </td>
  <td class="projectapproval">
  </td>
  ...
</table>
```

What I have is:

```
$('table td.projectapproval img.lockicon').length
```

Which will count the number of cells in the table with the lock icon.

What I want is to count the number of cells in the tables without the lock icon. Two in this case.

Does anyone know a good method to do this?

I could of course go:

```
$('table td.projectapproval).length - $('table td.projectapproval img.lockicon').length
```

But I really would like a cleaner way. Does one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('table td.projectapproval:not(:has(img.lockicon))')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use the filter function:

```
$('table td.projectapproval').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).children('img.lockicon').length;
    // use the find function if you're not looking for immediate children:
    return !$(this).find('img.lockicon').length;
})
```